# Fullscreen issue

Tags: javascript, html, web, fullscreen

I made a web application where i use a fullscreen plugin so that the users can enable and disable fullscreen mode trough a button.

The only problem is that when a user enables the fullscreen mode and then goes to a other page within the web application, the fullscreen mode automatically disables. Could somebody help me?

This button activates the fullscreen mode:

```
<a onclick="toggleScreen(document.documentElement);" href="#"><img class="screen" src="assets/admin/pages/img/fullscreen.png" /></a>
```

The fullscreen script:

```
// If fullscreen is active then close event
var toggle = 0;
      function toggleScreen(element)
{

  if(toggle == 0)
{

launchFullscreen(element);
toggle = 1;

} else {
 exitFullscreen();
toggle = 0;
}
}

// Find the right method, call on correct element
function launchFullscreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }

}

function exitFullscreen() {
  if(document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }
}

function dumpFullscreen() {
  console.log("document.fullscreenElement is: ", document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement || document.msFullscreenElement);
  console.log("document.fullscreenEnabled is: ", document.fullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullScreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled || document.msFullscreenEnabled);
}

// Events
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function(e) {
  console.log("fullscreenchange event! ", e);
});
document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function(e) {
  console.log("mozfullscreenchange event! ", e);
});
document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function(e) {
  console.log("webkitfullscreenchange event! ", e);
});
document.addEventListener("msfullscreenchange", function(e) {
  console.log("msfullscreenchange event! ", e);
});
```

Comment: you have some exit-fullscreen code in your launchFullscreen() function...

Comment: That part is for when the user clicks on the button again, the fullscreen function will disable.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to invoke your toggleScreen function onload of every web page you navigate to somehow.It will surely work.Cheers :)